# Angular RC 1 - Find out when a subscribe succeeds

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services, angular2-components

Im running into some issues since migrating to RC1 one of which is within one of my components, I have a service which grabs some json from a laravel api and subscribes to it then within the component I have the following

```
        import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
        import {ProjectsMainApi} from "../../../services/projects-main";

        declare var jQuery: any;
        declare var subscribe: any;

        import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

        @Component({
            selector: 'projects',
            templateUrl: './app/components/Projects/list/index.html',
            directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
        })

        export class ProjectsListComponent implements OnInit {

            elementRef: ElementRef;

            project: Object;

            constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, private _projectsmainapi: ProjectsMainApi) {
                this.elementRef = elementRef;
                this.project = this._projectsmainapi.project$;

                this._projectsmainapi.getProjectsMain();        
            }
            ngOnInit() {


                this.project.subscribe(() => {

                   alert('subscribed');

                });
            }
        }
```

the part that is failing it the lines

```
                this.project.subscribe(() => {

                   alert('subscribed');

                });
```

before upgrading the compiler compiled this no problem and it worked but since upgrading I am getting this error error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Object'.

My service file hasnt changed at all and is laid out as follows

```
    import {Http, Headers, Response} from "@angular/http"
    import {Injectable} from "@angular/core"
    import {IProjectsMain} from "../interfaces/IProjectsMain"
    import 'rxjs/Rx';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class ProjectsMainApi {

        apiUrl: string = "http://www.test.io/api/projects";

        headers: Headers = new Headers;

        project$: Observable<IProjectsMain[]>;

        private _ProjectsMainObserver: Observer<IProjectsMain[]>;

        private _dataStore: {

            project: IProjectsMain[]

        };

        constructor(private _http: Http) {

            this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

            //this.project$ = new Observable(observer => this._ProjectsMainObserver = observer).share();
            this.project$ = new Observable<IProjectsMain[]>(observer => this._ProjectsMainObserver = observer).share();
            this._dataStore = { project: [] };
        }

        public getProjectsMain() {

            this._http.get(this.apiUrl).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {

                this._dataStore.project = data.project;

                this._ProjectsMainObserver.next(this._dataStore.project);

            }, error => console.log('Could not load projects.'),
                () => "doneskies");

        }

    }
```

Having spent the day Googling and messing around with the code Im at a loss as to how I can fix this and make it compile so now Im hoping that someone may know how to tackle it another way i.e I need to be able to tell when a subscription happens and it succeeds but from within my component, the end result should trigger the alert thats in my component file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the variable `project` to `Observable<any>` or `Observable<IProjectsMain[]>` as in your service.

```
export class ProjectsListComponent implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;
    project: Observable<any>;
...
}
```

It was working before because you probably changed your `tsconfig.json` to have?:

```
"noEmitOnError": true
```

Comment: I will name my first child after you good sir. Brilliant stuff, I didnt even need to edit my tsconfig but you are probably right, I had updated it and im not sure what was in it before.. I am pretty new to angular 2 so I am just curious is there any concerns security or otherwise from casting variables as any or is it standard practice.. also just for dexterity in my controller I also added import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; in case anyone else is left scratching their head while starting out

Comment: thank you @user3461985, it will be a very long name though ;). About `any` It's not considered good practice for ease of readability and to get warning during compile time. But, once you are in runtime, the type of the object will not have any effect whatsoever since javascript doesn't have type checking by default. So, security wise, I doubt there is any impact on using `any`